# Why this javaScript code returns not defined

Tags: javascript

I am struggling to understand why the below code snippet returns `greeting is not defined`.
The purpose of this question isn't how I fix it but I understand why it throws this error.

```js
function sayHey() {
    var greeting = "Hello";
    if(greeting){
        greeting = "Hey";
       let greeting = "Hi";
        console.log(greeting);
    }
}

sayHey();
```

Comment: It should be throwing an error due to the temporal dead zone. Not sure why you get `undefined` instead.

Comment: I see `"Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'greeting' before initialization"`

Comment: Remove the ``let`` from ``let greeting``.

Comment: @Azametzin that still wouldn't produce the behaviour OP reported.